# get point from ol.geom.MultiPolygon

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to add a marker at the center or anywhere of my feature (ol.geom.MultiPolygon) and i cannot get the point (x,y) for it !!!

var   coordinates= feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

```
/** marker data */
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([coordinates[0][0][0], coordinates[0][0][1]]), /** if i do this it works: geometry: new ol.geom.Point([8420.360601958382, 12492.263314383097]), */
    name: 'Null Island',
    population: 4000,
    rainfall: 500
});
```

Thank;s again !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoints().getPoint(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i've found it:

```
var geo = feature.getGeometry();

var poly = geo.getPolygons().reduce(function(left, right) {
    return left.getArea() > right.getArea() ? left : right;
});

var point = poly.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
```

from the book: OpenLayers 3 : Beginner's Guide